# How to define multiple operations on the same route using Express Swagger Generator

Tags: node.js, express, npm, documentation, swagger

I'm using npm package [express-swagger-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-swagger-generator) and when i define 2 routes like this:

```
/**
 * @group Users - operations about user
 * @route GET /users
 * @route POST /users
 */
```

It only shows the POST route but not the GET route like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or733.png)

If i switch them it only shows the GET route and the same goes for defining them in seperate places using the @group tag twice.

How do I make both the POST and GET route on /users show up in my api docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/pgroot/express-swagger-generator), specifically at `swagger.js`, line 85:

```
parameters[route.uri] = {}
```

This line will basically wipe away any previously parsed methods/params/etc for a given route. The library does not seem to be designed or has not yet been developed far enough, to allow for multiple route registrations for a single function (or even on multiple functions - which seems like a deal breaker for me personally).

If this is something you prefer, I would suggest raising an issue against that repository, or even better. Raise the issue and raise a Pull Request for it.

On a personal note, I do believe the implementation could do with including this feature, as it's pretty common with today's REST-based APIs to expose the same path with multiple verbs.

A suggested change could look like this:

```
parameters[route.uri] = parameters[route.uri] || {}
parameters[route.uri][route.method] = parameters[route.uri][route.method]  || {}
```